# Timing - chart is shown too late

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My chart is ready now and you can see here an example:
http://www.ariva.de/gold-kurs/push-chart?boerse_id=36

There is one problem left: As we have a lot of advertising on our page, the chart renders only after all is ready, so sometimes the user has to wait some seconds. I think, Highcharts waits for document.ready? I do not, so code below.

Is there a possibility to control the order of the Javascript functions and show the chart earlier?

```
        $('#containerLast').highcharts( {  
            chart : {
                events : {
                    load : function() {
                        chartLast = this;
                        seriesLast = this.series[0];
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Yes, Higcharts should be created after DOM is loaded. Load asynchronously ads or add them after DOM is loaded and after chart creation.

Comment: It is too difficult to change the whole architecture of our page. So I'm looking for a solution in my Highstock-Component.

Comment: If you are not loading your ads after your main content, your main content will always suffer slower loading times like this.  Changing how your page loads is truly the best solution, for this problem and in general.  You might try loading your main content via AJAX instead, however...

Comment: You have your chart creation wrapped in a `.ready()` event (http://api.jquery.com/ready/),  this is the recommended way to do it.  Now you could try to inline your javascript (make sure it's after the `div` you are rendering to) but again it's bad practice (it would probably work though).

Comment: Thanks at all. @Mark: can you please explain what you mean or give me an example?

Comment: @KarinSuel, in your code you plot creation is wrapped in `$(function ()`, this will wait until the DOM is fully loaded before execution.  Instead place your plot creation right after your target div in the HTML: `<div id="highChartsTarget"></div><script>buildChart();</script>`.  If there is anything in your charting JS that requires DOM elements make sure they are loaded before the call.  Again, this is NOT generally a good thing to do.